# Implementation of respondsToSelector:

Tags: ios, protocols, nsobject

As i know respondsToSelector: is a method of NSObject Protocol ,but for all the methods in protocol the class which conforms to the protocol need to provide the implementation but all the protocols we create conforms to NSObject protocol but we don't provide any implementation for those methods.May be i am missing something obvious Plz bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to implement `-respondsToSelector:` in your own classes.  In fact you probably shouldn't.  The `NSObject` implementation will be able to figure it out itself at runtime.

Comment: :Thats exactly i wanted to know how it works without implementing anything

Comment: It's an aspect of the Objective-C runtime.  I recommend reading a book on Objective-C if you want to know how this happens behind the scenes.  Apple has some documentation on message sending which discusses it a bit as well: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html

Comment: Dear @vik, if you think that this answer is complete enough, please mark it as correct.